# What is different between function int get() and istream& get(char &c)

Tags: c++

I don't know What is different between function int get() and istream& get(char &c)
I have some codes like this.It is an endless loop. But it is fine if i use **ch = File.get()** instead of **File.get(ch)**. Tell me the reasons.

```
fstream File("input.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
char ch;
while (1)
{
    File.get(ch);
    //ch = File.get();
    cout << ch;
    if (ch == EOF) break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get):

> Reads one character and returns it if available. Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()`....

The overload that doesn't take arguments will return EOF when the read fails. The other overloads don't affect the passed parameter, and just put the stream in a failed state (the first overload does this too). Since you never check the stream's state, your loop continues forever.

You can change the loop to `while (File.get(ch))` and it will terminate when it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: Sorry! i couldn't understand your answer. can you  explain it more clearly again?

Comment: `File.get(ch)` won't set `ch` to anything when it reaches the EOF, it just changes some variables in `File`. `File.get()` _will_ return EOF when it hits the end, in addition to changing those variables.

Answer (score -2):

get() is a function which returns an integer which has to be assigned using the equals ( assignment ) operator.

istream is a class which has a method called get() which takes a parameter &c , and places a character into it.

**they are not the same get() but do similar things**

The function way of doing things is faster, but if you want to learn the Object Oriented way of doing things use the class way, and when you are experienced in both you can decide which way is appropriate for the task in hand.

Comment: They're both overloads of `get` in `basic_istream`. This doesn't answer the question of why one overload causes an infinite loop and the other doesn't. Also, operator overloads are functions, and C++ is not an OOP language, it is a multi-paradigm language that supports OOP among others.

Comment: A multi-paradigm can achieve things either using functions or class methods.  io functions are defined in stdio.h while io class methods are defined in stream.h ( #include <stream> ) which itself includes stdio.h ,  by not having include stream only the C functions are available.